# How to detect teeth using opencv

Tags: c++, opencv

- I am working on one project and in that i want to make teeth white. So for that need to find teeth part.I have tried equalizeHist, adaptiveThreshold, threshold,dilate, erode etc.But not getting exact teeth part.
- So can anyone tell me how can i do it.I am using OpenCV c++ library.
- In input i have this image

[image: inputImage]

- I have found this type of mask

[image: maskImage]

- So if i use this mask the image looks unnatural like this,

[image]

Comment: You mean teeth inside a mouth or teeth out ?

Comment: Have you tried face detection using haarCascades. That will narrow down your region of interest

Comment: @Pierre:teeth inside mouth

Comment: @SaranshKejriwal: Yes.I have already detect face.And i also have mouth rect.

Comment: Please post some sample images to give a clear idea of what you're working with

Comment: what about finding an average histogram from a couple hundred teeth in mouth photos normalizing the average and using that average histogram to apply a threshold mask and possibly bumping up the contrast areas using erosion and dilates? Also an image would help. Another approach is to put the image through gimp see if you can isolate the teeth region with a black and white binary image and then look at the docs to find the opencv equivalent?

Comment: Edit looks like you are already going straight to binary, perhaps work out the histogram thresholds and color saturation stuff first? There isn't much room in terms of contrast info its mostly based on hue.

Comment: can you please post some demo code for same?

Comment: Please note that this is a question and answer site, not a
code writing service. If you [edit] your question to
describe what you have tried so far and where you are stuck,
then we can try to help with specific problems. You should
also read [ask].

Comment: @TobySpeight: Don't say it is not code writing service.I have seen many questions here in that people post code.I have just asked for some demo code which gives me idea.

Answer (score 1):

I see two problems. You find the correct region, but the boundary is imprecise. That's solvable by looking at the gradient of the hue, which will form a clear contour. If you use the HSL color model, the Lightness component will likely have a sharp contrast too.

Secondly, the bigger effect IMO is that you far overdo the whitening. This loses a lot of contrast between teeth. You probably want to just drop the yellow saturation, but don't touch the luminosity.

If you want to be really fancy, determine where the teeth edges are, and you can smooth out the luminosity elsewhere. This removes small stains on teeth.

Comment: But i am unable to find clear contour.That;s what i m asking for.Can you please explain more about gradient of hue?

Comment: @Sagar: Convert your RGB to HSL colorspace, take gradient of Hue component. This would be a vector field, but you just need the magnitude at each point. (direction of gradient doesn't matter).

Comment: can you post some demo code?

Comment: Hey @MSalters, interesting approach! Can you explain what is the "gradient of Hue component". I searched online but couldn't find an explanation

Comment: @RoiMulia: Colors can be represented as "RGB" triplets, but also as Hue, Saturation, Lightness (HSL). In that model, Hue is basically the rainbow color. A gradient, simply said, is the difference between adjacent pixels. In this case, you'd look at the difference in Hue.

Comment: @MSalters Awesome! I'm actually some good progress regards the teeth whitening process. I was able to isolate the mouth region, and now I'm stuck on the actual whitening process (production-worthy one). If I understand you suggested to pre-define the yellow range and only the relevant pixels Sat. But if we are speaking on a real-world app that needs to work for many cases, would it better to actually "sample" the teeth of the input image (assuming we can pin-point them), and create the range from the actual teeth input? so it'll work for every input? What do you think?